# How can my function fork for few seconds in java?

Tags: java, android

Im making apk in android studio,in java,and I need to my button change color for few seconds.For example,if the original color is blue,it needs to get changed to red for one second and get back to blue.

Comment: show what have you done yet and your code

Comment: You may be looking for `postDelayed`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Handler().postDelayed` method on click of button to achieve your goal. Check the code below for reference:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                button.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(R.color.yourSecondaryColor));
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        button.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(R.color.yourBaseColor));
                    }
                },1000);
            }
        });
```

You can change the time according to your needs. Just change 1000 to your required value.

Answer (score 0):

Using threads:
After changing colors use:

```
 Thread.sleep(1000);
```

and then change color again

Comment: suggest it in your answer, then